# How to align two divs side by side in center?

Tags: html, css

Look: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak334/

I'm trying to put the divs `div_vagas_disponiveis` and `div_percentual_vagas` side by side, and alining in center of the div `fieldset`. What am i missing?

Comment: Remove unrelated crap when showing examples please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
#div_vagas_disponiveis {
   display: inline-block;
}
#div_percentual_vagas {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

here is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak334/3/

good luck!

**EDIT:**

now check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak334/9/

if found this hacks on google:

```
display: inline-block; /* FF2*/
vertical-align: top; /* BASELINE CORRECCIÓN*/
zoom: 1; /* IE7 (hasLayout)*/
*display: inline; /* IE */
_height: 20px; /* IE6 */
```

and I check it on chrome, IE7 and IE8

this is the link where I found it (in spanish):

http://ferticidio.com/display-inline-block-para-ie-y-los-demas-navegadores

Comment: Does IE8 understand the *hack? I thought not, unless it was in compat (ie7) mode.  Also, not sure what the zoom is for: display: inline-block puts haslayout to true on the element already, and setting it back to display: inline does not undo Haslayout.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Ak334/2/

```
  <div style="width:270px;margin:0px auto;">
```

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni your counters will not have 100% width - it not logicle. you should put some max wsith for them - or use Javascript .....

Comment: Why can you not use fixed width? Is this supposed to be a responsive layout?  Figure out the em with or rem width/% width.  You need to have some sort of widths set to div_vagas_disponieveis and div_percentual_vegas otherwise the browser is going to assume 100% width for those divs.

Comment: There is a way to use something like `display: inline-block` to solve this problem, instead putting fixed width?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni IMHO you can. but i dont think it will be supported in all browsers.(maybe im wrong). try it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir yep. You're right. The solution of MCSI doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni you have no other options ( except JS) . use fixed reasonable width for the counters . thats it. ( it will also better performance since the browser doesnt need to calc the width - it has its value....)

Answer (score 0):

Use following CSS

```
#fieldset div   // you should think about changing id "fieldset is a HTML tag"
{
   display:inline-block;
}
```